# push notification is not received by device through gcm google api and php server

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql),
and I managed to register the application in the cgm server with device
but I canno't receive push notification from server to device
I tested on genymotion emulator and real device but always no notification received on device
I don't know the error and the don't knwo how can I fix this issue

Here is the method which send push notification:

```
    /**
 * Sending Push Notification
 */
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    // include config
    include_once './config.php';

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

I have set the api key and project id and all is done.

Comment: Please post the response your server gets from Google, as well as your client code (the manifest and the BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: from where I can get them

Comment: here is the string returned by this function: Unauthorized

Error 401

Comment: That means you are probably not using a valid API_KEY.

Comment: then,what should I do

Comment: Did you create a Google API project and generated an API key?

Comment: yes I did but I have this erro

Comment: Did you add your project name `com.blah.blah..` in the Google portal?

Comment: no, but it is not obligatory

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$apiKey = "your api key goes here (use browser api)";
$headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:" . "key=" . $apiKey);
```